# How to deallocate WKInterfaceController

Tags: objective-c, watchos-2

I have a WKInterfaceController subclass with some labels on it. I implemented `dealloc` in my source code. I've inserted an `NSLog` in the `dealloc` method. When I dismiss the interface controller the dealloc is never called. I run instrument on the app, the interface is allocating 0.2MB into the memory and when dismissed it will free up 0.1MB, the other 0.1MB is kept in the memory, I tried setting all the outlets to nil in the `willDeactivate` method but doesn't work. Seems like some pointers are retaining the interface controller. How can I remove these pointers and deallocate the interface controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of playing around with my codes, I figured out that it wasn't the button and the label's fault, I've scheduled some invocations using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and it wasn't canceled. So to do that cancel all scheduled invocations using:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

And it will remove any scheduled invocations so your controller can be deallocated.